# onsubmit="return submitForm()" is not calling javascript function submitForm() (Thymeleaf)

Tags: javascript, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am new in thymeleaf and want to execute javascript function . After click on submit button same page is loading with changed url and  not able to call javascript function (submitForm), while it is written in the code as :   . Please help me on this how to execute javascript function submitForm from  tag as provided.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-
              scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>

    <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/css/bootstrap.min.css}"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" id="css-main" th:href="@{/css/oneui.css}"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
          th:href="@{/css/custom.css}"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
          th:href="@{//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-
          awesome.min.css}"/>
</head>

<body class="asset-management">
    <div id="page-container" class="sidebar-l sidebar-o side-scroll">
        <main id="main-container" class="light-blue-bg" th:style="@{padding-left: 50px;}">
            <div id="note" class="custom-element-hidden alert">
                <span class="msg"></span>
                <span id="noteClose" class="note-close"><!-- &times;  -->
              </span>
            </div>
            <div id="olapartnerbody" class="row wide">
                <div th:if="${InstaDLState==1 and InstaDLStateStatus==0}">
                    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
                    </script>

                    <script type="text/javascript">
                    function submitForm() {
                        console.log('inside submitForm function');
                        var x =
                        document.getElementById("iv_state_1").getElementsByTagName("input");
                        var len = x.length-1;

                        for(var i=0; len > i; i++) {
                            var element = x[i];
                            if(element.name === "name" ||
                                    element.name === "fatherName" ||
                                    element.name === "gender" ||
                                    element.name === "mobileNumber" ||
                                    element.name === "dl_file" ||
                                    element.name === "city" ||
                                    element.name === "dob" ||
                                    element.name === "alternateMobileNumber" ||
                                    element.name === "dlId") {
                                if(element.value === "") {
                                    console.log("Mandatory fields are empty");
                                    return false;
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        $("#dl_document").submit();

                        console.log(document.getElementById("dl_file_id"));

                        if(document.getElementById("dl_file_id").value === "") {
                            console.log("dl_file_id is empty : " + document.getElementById("dl_file_id").value);
                            return false;
                        }
                        var form = $("#iv_state_1");
                        var formStr = JSON.stringify(getFormData(form));
                        console.log(formStr);

                        $.ajax({async:false,
                            url:"http://localhost:8080/submit",
                            type:"post",
                            data:formStr,
                            contentType:"application/json",
                            processData:false,
                            success: function(data) {
                            console.log(data);
                                window.location.reload();
                            },
                            error: function(data) {
                                console.log(data);
                            }
                        });
                        return false;
                    }

                    function getFormData($form){
                        var unindexed_array = $form.serializeArray();
                        var indexed_array = {};

                        $.map(unindexed_array, function(n, i){
                            indexed_array[n['name']] = n['value'];
                        });
                        return indexed_array;
                    }

                    function uploadDocument() {
                        console.log('checking once !!!!');
                        var uploadForm = $("#dl_document");
                        var formData = new FormData(uploadForm);
                        var fileInput =  document.getElementById("dl_file");
                        var size = Math.round((fileInput.files[0].size/1024/1024)*100)/100;
                        console.log('value is ' + size);

                        if(size>2) {
                            alert('File size too large it should be less than 2 MB');
                            document.getElementById('dl_file').value = "";
                            return false;
                        }

                        $.ajax({async:false,
                                url:"http://staging-docyard-pub-1689750444.ap-southeast-1.elb.amazonaws.com/documents/ola-staging/upload",
                                type:"post",
                                data:formData,
                                processData:false,
                                beforeSend: function(request) {
                                request.setRequestHeader("X-Creator-Id","cvs");
                                request.setRequestHeader("X-Folder-Name","deviceplatform/cvs/test1");
                                request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/octet-stream");
                                request.setRequestHeader("X-File-Name","file4");
                                request.setRequestHeader("X-File-Size","240");
                            },
                            success: function(data){
                                console.log(data);
                                console.log('@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@');
                                console.log(data.id.document_id);
                                $("#dl_file_id").val(data.id.document_id);
                            },

                            error: function(e){
                                console.log(e);
                            }
                        })
                        return false;
                    }
                    </script>

                    <form id="dl_document" onchange="return uploadDocument()">
                        <input id="dl_file" required="required" type="file"
                               name="dlImage" accept="image/*"/>
                    </form>

                    <form id="iv_state_1" onsubmit="return submitForm()">

                        <input type="hidden" name="tid"
                               th:value="${InstaveritasType}"/><br/><br/><br/>
                        <label><b>Name</b></label>
                        <input required="required" type="text" placeholder="Enter Name"
                               name="name"/><br/><br/><br/>

                        <label><b>Father Name</b></label>
                        <input required="required" type="text" placeholder="Enter Father Name"
                               name="fatherName"/><br/><br/><br/>

                        <label><b>Gender</b></label>
                        <input required="required" type="text" placeholder="Gender"
                               name="gender"/><br/><br/><br/>

                        <label><b>Mobile Number</b></label>
                        <input required="required" type="text" placeholder="Mobile Number"
                               name="mobileNumber"/><br/><br/><br/>

                        <label><b>City</b></label>
                        <input required="required" type="text" placeholder="City"
                               name="city"/><br/><br/><br/>
                        <label><b>Date of Birth</b></label>
                        <input required="required" placeholder="Date of Birth"
                               class="textbox-n" type="text" onfocus="(this.type='date')"
                               onblur="(this.type='text')" id="date" name="dob"/><br/><br/>
                        <br/>
                        <label><b>Alternate Mobile Number</b></label>
                        <input required="required" type="text"
                               placeholder="Alternate Mobile Number"
                               name="alternateMobileNumber"/><br/><br/><br/>

                        <label><b>dl Number</b></label>
                        <input required="required" type="text" placeholder="dl Number" name="dlId"/><br/><br/>
                        <br/> <input type="submit"/>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </main>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: change `onsubmit="return submitForm()"` to `onsubmit="submitForm()"`. Also make sure you return `true` from `submitForm` so that the form gets submitted. Returning `false` or `undefined` will prevent form submission.

Comment: Why are you returning a function,, just call the function and return it in function.. onclick= submitForm()

Comment: Do you have enters in the url in your actual code as well? Formatting the code would already help a lot.

Comment: @Panther i did , not working as after click on submit button same page is loading and also i have put console.log in function which is not printing in console. console is blank

Comment: @VinodkumarG Not working sir :( , i did like that : <input type="submit" onclick="submitForm()"/> and remove onsubmit from <form> tag.

Comment: after click on submit button url has changed to "http://localhost:8080/type/?tid=dl_1&name=abs&fatherName=pqr&gender=male&mobileNumber=7667686767&city=qwerty&dob=2017-10-18&alternateMobileNumber=7667486767&dlId=1211312" having same page

Comment: There is problem in this line,, the url is not correctly formatted.   $.ajax({async:false,
    url:"http://staging-docyard-pub-1689750444.ap-southeast-
   1.elb.amazonaws.com/documents/ola-staging/upload", Kindly format the codes neatly and try.

Comment: @VinodkumarG not understand how to format , if you dont mind plzz help me on this because same has been running succesfully without using css

Comment: Url should not be broken like this,,$.ajax({async:false,
    url:"http://staging-docyard-pub-1689750444.ap-southeast-
   1.elb.amazonaws.com/documents/ola-staging/upload", instead use concatination use below one
$.ajax({async:false,
    url:"http://staging-docyard-pub-1689750444.ap-southeast1.elb.amazonaws.com/documents/ola-staging/upload",
or use url :"asdfasdfsdf"+"asdfsdfsdf" it should not be in two different lines @User120909